# Php Calculation Showing incorrect output within multple and plus operator calculation

Tags: php, operators, calculation, integer-arithmetic

Here title maybe common but i searched for last 5 hours on my code, on php.net and here but nothing match my problem. My problem is i want to calculate two variable. but why its not calculating correctly.

```
    $qty = 0;
        $cqty = 0;
        $price = 0;
        $cprice = 0;                                    
        $gprice = 0;                                    
        $hprice = 0;
        $tprice = 0;
        $i = 1;
            foreach( $details  as $index => $detail) {?>
                                                    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $detail['item_name']; ?></td>
        <td class="right"><?php echo $detail['quantity']; ?></td>
    <td class="right"><?php echo number_format((float)$detail['purchase_price'], 2); ?></td>
        <td class="right"><?php echo number_format((float)$detail['quantity']*$detail['purchase_price'], 2); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $details2[$index]['item_name']; ?></td>
        <td class="right"><?php echo $details2[$index]['cquantity']; ?></td>
        <td class="right"><?php echo number_format((float)$details2[$index]['cpurchase_price'], 2); ?></td>
        <td class="right"><?php echo number_format((float)$details2[$index]['cquantity']*$details2[$index]['cpurchase_price'], 2); ?></td></tr>
<?php
$qty += $detail['quantity'];
$cqty += $details2[$index]['cquantity'];
$price +=  (number_format((float)$detail['quantity'] *$detail['purchase_price'], 2));
$cprice +=  (number_format((float)$details2[$index]['cquantity'] * $details2[$index]['cpurchase_price'], 2));

$gprice = (double) $price; 
$hprice = (double) $cprice;
$tprice +=  $gprice + $hprice;                                        
$i++;
} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="space20"></div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4 invoice-block pull-right">
<ul class="unstyled amounts">
<li><strong>Sub - Total amount :</strong> <?php echo number_format((float)$price, 2); ?> </li>
<li><strong>Grand Total :</strong> <?php echo number_format((float)$cprice, 2); ?> </li>
<li><strong>cccGrand Total :</strong> <?php echo number_format((float)$tprice, 2); ?> </li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

My question is in showing correct calculation between price+cprice=tprice. Suppose price=170,cprice=520 so tprice=690. But output showing tprice=1890.I am totally unable to figure out how the output calculated. 
[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwbjm.jpg)

Comment: Please provide proper code snippets so we could properly help you.

The snippets you provide missing the $details variable which include values needed for the calculation.

Comment: You may skip that part. $details variable output correct data. you can see in image screenshot. problem is in adding 2 output of those variable. when i try to calculate, its calculating incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just don't use number_format when calculating values because it will give a string not a number:

```
$qty += $detail['quantity'];
$cqty += $details2[$index]['cquantity'];
$price +=  (float)$detail['quantity'] *$detail['purchase_price'];
$cprice +=  (float)$details2[$index]['cquantity'] * $details2[$index]['cpurchase_price'];

$gprice = (double) $price; 
$hprice = (double) $cprice;
$tprice +=  $gprice + $hprice;                                        
$i++;
```

Comment: Since the output of group totals uses `number_format` which actually performs commercial rounding, the same behaviour should be reflected in the sum calculation. Half quantities or prices like 1.499 could be introduced in the shop sooner or later and then a bug will occur. You are correct that `number_format` does not work, however, it must not be deleted without substitution. Just use the `round` function.

Comment: you may got me wrong, i am getting number or string when i try without  number_format. but result is not what it should be. like  it should $a+$b=$c but i got $a+$b=$e. where $a=2, $b=4, $c=6, $e=9

Comment: When you accumulate a value using number_format will give you surprising result.

Comment: You can use number_format for displaying final result but not for accumulating like this `$price +=  (number_format((float)$detail['quantity'] *$detail['purchase_price'], 2));
$cprice +=  (number_format((float)$details2[$index]['cquantity'] * $details2[$index]['cpurchase_price'], 2));`